# How can I create an infinite property?

Tags: c#, class, properties

In the C# , string has infinite property like this

```
string a = "";
a.ToString().Length.ToString().ToUpper().ToLower().ToString()....
```

and how can I create like this

```
ClassName a = new ClassName();
a.text("message").title("hello").icon("user");
```

thanks, it works

```
    public class Modal
    {
        public Modal()
        {

        }

        private string Date = null;
        private string Text = null;
        private string Title = null;
        private string Icon = null;
        private string Subtitle = null;
        private string Confirm = "ok";
        private string Cancel = "cancel";
        private string Type = "warning";

        public Modal text(string text) { this.Text = text; return this; }

        public Modal title(string title) { this.Title = title; return this; }

        public Modal icon(string icon) { this.Icon = icon; return this; }

        public Modal subtitle(string subtitle)
        {
            this.Subtitle = subtitle;
            return this;
        }

        public Modal confirm(string confirm) { this.Confirm = confirm; return this; }

        public Modal cancel(string cancel) { this.Cancel = cancel; return this; }

        public Modal type(string type) { this.Type = type; return this; }

        public void show(System.Web.UI.Page Page)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.Append("{'date':'" + (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - 621355968000000000).ToString() + "','text':'" + Text + "','title':'" + Title + "','icon':'" + Icon + "','subtitle':'" + Subtitle + "','confirm':'" + Confirm + "','cancel':'" + Cancel + "','type':'" + Type + "'}");
            string _script = "showModal(" + s.ToString() + ");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - 621355968000000000).ToString(), _script, true);
        }

    }
```

```
Modal m = new Modal();
m.text("this is text").title("this is title").icon("fa-car").type("danger").show(this);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otl0L.png)

Comment: It doesn't have "infinite property" - it just has various methods which return`string`. If you make your methods return the same type, you can do that too...

Comment: Your example will not even compile as Length is an int not a string. There are no properties, just chained functions.

Comment: I don't think you can do `a.ToString().Length.ToUpper()` since `Length` is an `int` .. as @JonSkeet mentioned, as long as each method returns a `string` you can keep on calling `string` methods on the result

Comment: Fluent interface/Method chaining is what you need to research, E.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640997/Fluent-interfaces-and-Method-Chaining-in-Csharp

Comment: Also see http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every one of those methods on `string` simply return a `string`.  (Well, almost.  You have a `.Length` in there which isn't correct.)  If you return your object from your methods, you can achieve the same concept.  (In some cases this can be referred to as a "fluent syntax", though the `string` example isn't necessarily really that.)

For example, say your `.Title()` method is as such:

```
class ClassName
{
    //...

    public ClassName Title(string title)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then any time you call `someObj.Title("some string")` that method will return the object itself:

```
var someObj = new ClassName();
someObj.Title("some title").SomeOtherOperation();
```

It's not "infinite", it's just a method that returns the same type on which it's invoked.  It can return *itself* or any instance of that type.  Just be sure to pay attention to the interface you're building when you do this, because you could accidentally create fairly unintuitive things.  (Fluent chains which produce unintended side-effects on the original object or don't produce intended effects on the original object.)

Comment: thank you your answer , i will try it out